# Add hotspots using html elements instead of images, in panolens

Tags: javascript, jquery, virtual-reality, 360-panorama

I'm using panolens for creating a 360 image view, which came out quite well. panolens is providing imageloader.js by default to insert .png images as hotspot, but i need to insert 'html element' as hotspot.

Any idea or help on how it could be done? Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks very much